# CKEditor 4.5.0 BETA fileUpload API issue

Tags: file-upload, ckeditor

I'm trying **CKEditor 4.5.0 BETA** because it let me paste images from the clipboard in all browsers, but I can't find any documentation regarding the File Upload API (new?), the example in [This Link](http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/image-upload.html) uses CKFinder but I don't have it, I need to create my own Server Side code in PHP (I'm using **Larevel 4**).

When I try to upload a file, the only parameter in the request is the file (named "upload"), how do I connect my CKEditor instance with my server? maybe something is missing?

```
CKEDITOR.replace('newticket', {
            extraPlugins    : 'uploadimage,image2',
            uploadUrl       : '/ckeditor/newticket/uploads',

            height                  : '200px',
            toolbar                 : [
                { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
                { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ] },
                { name: 'lists', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote' ] },
                { name: 'insert', items: ['Link', '-', 'HorizontalRule'] },
                { name: 'font', items: [ 'Format', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor'] }
            ]
        });
```

**EDIT 1**

I use this code in my Server Side (Laravel 4), the file is uploaded and CKeditor displays a message saying that the file is uploaded correctly but it doesn't add the img tag to the document

```
public function uploadFilesFromCKeditor() {

    if(Input::hasFile('upload')) {

        $fileName = sha1(time() . Input::file('upload')->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . Input::file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $success = Input::file('upload')->move(public_path() . '/ckeditor/uploads', $fileName);

        if($success) {

            $jsonResponse = array(
                'fileName'  => $fileName,
                'url'       => 'ckeditor/uploads/' . $fileName,
                'uploaded'  => 'true',
                'error'     => array(
                    'message'   => ''
                )
            );

        } else {

            $jsonResponse = array(
                'fileName'  => Input::file('upload')->getClientOriginalName(),
                'url'       => '',
                'uploaded'  => 'false',
                'error'     => array(
                    'message'   => 'Error msg'
                )
            );

        }

        return Response::json($jsonResponse);

    } else {

        $jsonResponse = array(
            'fileName'  => '',
            'url'       => '',
            'uploaded'  => 'false',
            'error'     => array(
                'message'   => 'error msg'
            )
        );

        return Response::json($jsonResponse);

    }

}
```

[image: ckeditor message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the feature is in the beta version at that moment, the full tutorial is not created yet, but you should be able to handle it based on the events docs.

If you get the request with the single entry `upload` which contains file it means you are on the good way, this is the default request which is send. If you want to modify it use [`fileUploadRequest` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadRequest).

CKEditor expects to receive JSON as a response, so all you need to do on the server side is to save the file (using PHP function `move_uploaded_file`, see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and return (`echo`) JSON data.

You can find the expected JSON response format and the example how to handle any other response [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadResponse).

Comment: I can't get the Editor to add the image after the upload, I will edit my question to explain

Comment: No, image should be added automatically. Do you have any content in the editable element (check with the DOM inspector), maybe an `<img>` with the empty `src`? Did something appears in the editor during the upload (there should be an image placeholder)? If the upload is too fast to see it add some delay on the server side. Placeholder should be replaced by the final image by this: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js#L52 what is called from here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/uploadwidget/plugin.js#L229

Comment: I checked the source but there is nothing there :P I'll try to delay the upload to see if there is any change

Comment: I tried delaying but still nothing, the tag doesn't appear

Comment: Try to put debugger in the methods I mentioned, also debug paste event (especially this listener: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/uploadwidget/plugin.js#L151) and find where data are removed.

Comment: The only way to follow a thread on SO is to leave a comment... so I'm leaving one :).

Comment: PS. If you would be able to reproduce this with a simple PHP script, then please share it - we could check it too.

Comment: Hello! I solved it, when I red boolean in the uploaded parameter type I thought I needed to send true :p I checked the request from the demo page and I realized that it was sending uploaded: 1, so I tried just sending 1 or 0 and it worked, really dumb mistake

Comment: Now I have another issue which is setting the image width with the htmlFilter and dataFilter :P that for some reason are not working, but that's a different question

Comment: Hello! I was Wrong! you can send true in the uploaded parameter, but for the image upload to work you need to include the 'Image' to the toolbar :p

Comment: Great to hear this! :D If you don't want the image button in the toolbar you can also use `editor.addFeature( editor.getCommand( 'image' ) )` (but the plugin needs to be enabled anyway) or you can use `config.extraAllowedContent`.